# trying to loop to the beginning of a function(sort of) in python

Tags: python, function, loops

I am trying to go back to the top of a function (not restart it, but go to the top) but can not figure out how to do this. Instead of giving you the long code I'm just going to make up an example of what I want:

```
used = [0,0,0]  
def fun():
   score = input("please enter a place to put it: ")
   if score == "this one":
      score [0] = total
   if score == "here"
      if used[1] == 0:
        score[1] = total
        used[1] = 1
      elif used[1] == 1:
        print("Already used")
        #### Go back to score so it can let you choice somewhere else. 
  list = [this one, here]
```

I need to be able to go back so essentially it forgets you tried to use "here" again without wiping the memory. All though I know they are awful, I basically need a go to but they don't exist in python. Any ideas?

*Edit: Ah sorry, I forgot to mention that when it's already in use, I need to be able to pick somewhere else for it to go (I just didn't want to bog down the code). I added the score == "this one"- so if I tried to put it in "here", "here" was already taken, it would give me the option of redoing score = input("") and then I could take that value and plug it into "this one" instead of "here". Your loop statement will get back to the top, but doesn't let me take the value I just found and put it somewhere else. I hope this is making sense:p

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary +1 you should post that as a proper answer.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is a `while` loop. You want to set up your loop to keep going until a place is found. Something like this:

```
def fun():
    found_place = False
    while not found_place:
        score = input("please enter a place to put it: ")
        if score == "here"
            if used[1] == 0:
                score[1] = total
                used[1] = 1
                found_place = True
            elif used[1] == 1:
                print("Already used")
```

That way, once you've found a place, you set `found_place` to `True` which stops the loop. If you haven't found a place, `found_place` remains `False` and you go through the loop again.

Answer (score 1):

As Ashwini correctly points out, you should do a `while` loop

```
def fun():
  end_condition = False
  while not end_condition:
    score = input("please enter a place to put it: ")
    if score == "here":
      if used[1] == 0:
        score[1] = total
        used[1] = 1
      elif used[1] == 1:
        print("Already used")
```

Comment: Erm, did you forget to add `end_condition = True` somewhere?  (-: